# Why fiber optic Sagnac interferometers don't produce multiple interference fringes

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, interferometry, fiber-optics

I have seen a few Sagnac fiber optic interferometers however, those that I've seen don't produce multiple fringes but rather just one luminant dot with varying intensity. Even if a beam expander is installed still there are no fringes but only one light dot. What is the reason for this behavior. Here is an example of a fiber Sagnac setup with a beam expander.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fm7zLp3m8b4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fibre is a single mode fibre and the phase is therefore associated with the mode as a whole varying along the longitudinal direction. The interference thus only determines which output port gets how much of the wave. There is no transverse phase variation.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how a phase which "is therefore associated with the mode as a whole varying along the longitudinal direction" produces "transverse phase variation" If the phase is longitudinal so the variations should be longitudinal.

Comment: @Jimski im 100% sure that flippiefanus made an extremely commonly seen typo and it should read "There is no transverse phase variation", and not "...now...".

Comment: Yes, silly typo. I corrected it.